# Magento2: how to handle data if FPC is enable

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I have scenario where I am adding data in custom session variable from helper.
when I am  accessing that data on Phtml by helper call it is not retrieving as FPC is enable.

If I disable FPC then it is retrieving.

Please suggest what is the best way to bypass FPC in above scenario.

**Note: data is retrieving from helper not from block as we can bypass block but in this case I am using helper.**